# Temporarily hiding an Activity window?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am launching an activity which displays a ListView.  When an item is selected from the ListView, I setResult() and finish().  The main Activity then receives the value from setResult() and (for example) runs another Activity which loads a picture in an ImageView.

Problem is, as control is being transferred from the ListView, back to to main, and then finally the ImageView, the main activity screen slides in and out rather quickly cbefore the ImageView activity is visible.

Any way to tell the main Activity not to redraw during the transition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could (based on the users choice) call your Activity (the one with the Gallery) from your ListView and after you fired the Intent, you finish it (if you don't want it in the Activity Stack). Like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
this.startActivity(i);
this.finish();
```